# Post comment via graph api to social plugin box

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Is there a way to post comment via graph API to social plugin? I'm developing an android App and I want to implement discussion via Facebook but I can't see any way how to achieve this. I saw some other questions about it but i wanted to ask on "official" Facebook stack overflow

Comment: Good point! I need this to... I create a link post on our facebook profile from my app, but also use the comments plugin. I need all comments on this post to show on the website. So I need to comment on the plugin manually now to get replies on this comment on facebook on the website.

Comment: Probably no :(
This is the replay when I try to post a comment via Graph api.
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}`

Comment: Agree with Omer, doesn't look like this is possible. Although you can read the comments out with Graph API by getting the page's object id and then calling GET /[id]/comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not possible. On offical Facebook developer support page i get that answer from FB developer. Too bad